# script test for .NET or regular PE exe

Tags: linux

I need to test in a shell script if an exe file is a .NET or regular Windows PE executable (without running it).

Use case:

- associate .exe files with this script in Linux.
- Launch wine or mono according to the format detected.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i've found by now:

```
file "runme.exe" | grep -i ".net"
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    EXEPATH="mono runme.exe"
else
    EXEPATH="wine runme.exe"
fi
```